# remove tags from around a string

Tags: jquery

```
<div>
<span>
          <span style="font-weight: bold;">MyName</span>
</span>
</div>
```

How would I be able to remove the span around MyName but leave the initial span?

Thanks

Comment: Without a way to identify the span it's not really possible except if you want to remove all nested spans. Can you change the HTML? give it a class for example.

Comment: What's your starting point? A click on "MyName"? Page load?

Comment: Have changed the code to show how each line starts as

Answer (score 1):

Use [**.unwrap()**](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) in conjuction with [.contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/):

```
$('#innerspan').contents().unwrap();​
```

*markup*:

```
<span>
  <span id="innerspan" style="font-weight: bold;">MyName</span>
</span>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/M3yNX/)

Answer (score 0):

Turn the string into elements and get the HTML content of the span:

```
s = $(s).html();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do next this time:

```
$('span').each(function() {  
   if ($(this).html() == "MyName") {
   $(this).parent().html("MyName");
  }
});
```

But it's very localized code.